# How to evaluate this expression

Tags: java

The value of int a=5;
So what's the value of:

```
a=a+ ++a + a;
```

Is it 17 or 18 ?
Please show the steps.

```
a=5+6+6=17 
//or
a=6+6+6=18 // as increment operator has the highest precedence
```

Comment: Have you trying executing it using java ? what does it show ?

Comment: Write a code and run....

Comment: it shows 17.But i don't know why

Comment: This might actually be indeterminate.  Some specs are silent on exactly when the ++ operator is executed.  I can't recall what Java says though.

Comment: @markspace it is defined in the JLS.

Comment: my confusion is whether the increment operator will be evaluated first and therefore value of a will become 6 and result will be 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the JLS, subexpressions are evaluated from left to right. That's why the first term is evaluated to 5, the second one is evaluated to 6 and third one is evaluated after the second one so it gives 6. That's why the sum is 17.

Comment: @SouhardyaMondal Java Language Specification.

Comment: where can i know get that?

Comment: @SouhardyaMondal You can just google for it.

Comment: but then operator precedence is not followed? @ILoveCoding as the increment operator has highest precedence

Comment: @SouhardyaMondal Precedence is followed. But the order of evaluation of subexpressions matters, too. The first term is evaluated before the second one.

Comment: I am getting confused.
If precedence is followed  then ++a should be evaluated first.Ain't it? @ILoveCoding

Comment: @SouhardyaMondal No. Precedence means that `++a` is evaluated before addition. It does not mean that it should be evaluated before the first term(`a`) is evaluated.

Comment: i could not understand